# Setting thread affinity for WCF DuplexChannelFactory service

Tags: multithreading, wcf, affinity

Is it possible to set the thread affinity for a WCF service? When I instantiate my service I want all of it's processing to be constrained to a single core.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set ConcurrencyMode to ConcurrencyMode.Single and ConcurrencyMode to ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant.

[WCF InstanceContextMode, ConcurrencyMode, and Server-side Threading](http://kennyw.com/indigo/178)

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
public class Service : IService
{
    // Implementation code
}
```

You can also set MaxConcurrentCalls, MaxConcurrentInstances  and MaxConcurrentSessions.

[Throttling in WCF](http://kennyw.com/work/indigo/150).

Comment: Thanks for the reply it is helpful with other aspects of our platform but it does not answer my question. Assume I have a machine with four cores. I want to start four WCF clients that will receive a callback from a controller telling them to calculate something and I need to make sure that one and only one calculator is running on a single core.

Comment: @user481779 - So in your solution clients do the calculation, right? So you want to limit the number of cores that clients running on, not server?